# 403 Request rate higher than configured

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

When I'm adding members to Google Groups I'm receiving a `403 Request rate higher than configured` error. This is happening for all applications, including the API Explorer on the Google developer website.

Even if I make only a single request in 12+ hours I still receive the error.
I've confirmed the Admin API has plenty of quota remaining on the project.

It is happening only for a single Apps for Education domain.

**Request:**

```js
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/[redacted]%40ryan.catholic.edu.au/members?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "email": "<redacted>",
 "role": "MEMBER"
}
```

**Response:**

```js
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Request rate higher than configured."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Request rate higher than configured."
 }
}
```

Comment: The above error is thrown when limit of concurrent requests for a certain operation has been reached. You need to slow down the requests, this can be done by implementing exponential back off. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

Comment: I realise that. However it happens on a single request over 12 hours after the last request. It is also affecting all applications, including the API explorer in Google.

Comment: @SGC I'm running round in circles with support on this. If the issue is reproducible through the API explorer should I assume it's a problem at Google's end? My ticket is #06532690

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a partial resolution to this.

**Issue Summary:**

- API returns '403 Request rate higher than configured' on certain requests, even after no requests are made for a long period of time (12+hrs) to a single domain.
- Attempting to use a different Client ID or and user return the same error code. It also impacts the API Explorer.

**Cause:**

- Certain operations can trigger a "black-listing" of a **domain**  (not an application) for abuse. There may be undocumented limits on specific operations within a time period.

**Resolution:**

- Support receive a notification of this blacklisting and can remove the flag.

---

In our case we were likely adding too many members to too many groups in a 24 hour period and triggered an undocumented limit (support couldn't tell me what the limit was). We're still waiting for the black-listing to be removed from our domain.

This problem does raise additional questions however:

- The API limit documentation https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits does not appear to be complete. There appears to be additional limits that can trigger a "domain" black-list. What are these limits?
- Why does a Google Apps Domain become black-listed rather than the application making the requests?
- Why aren't the Domain Administrator's notified of a black-listing of their domain?

Comment: Unfortunately, while support can see the blacklisting, they don't seem to be able to remove it. Still working with support to try and fix it, but it's been almost a month now with no resolution :(

Comment: Peter, do you have some more context about this? Specifically where did you get this information and in what context. Would like to look into this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We just hit this 3/16/16, does anyone know if this has been resolved? Should I immediately engage support or do they correctly remove the blacklisting automatically now after a time period.

That will teach me not to run two syncs, even with limited changes within 30 minutes of each other.

I know this is an old thread but it seems that others might still be experiencing this and advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question and shouldn't be posted as such.  This isn't a discussion thread like that.  There are guidelines on how to use the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  If you have a new question relating to this then start a new question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would engage support immediately. We disabled syncs for almost a week, and that wasn't enough to remove the blacklisting.